# Unzip terminal mac french accent

Tags: macos, terminal, unzip, french

How can I unzip a .zip file with french accent (folders and files have accent some time) with the app terminal on macOS 10.13.5?

For exemple with this command :

```
unzip file.zip
```

some folder with accent is like this:
**ba%A6%E9ton_TBF** but the real name is **bâton_TBF**

Thanks !

Comment: What does not work with `unzip bâton_TBF/file.zip` ? I think your default shell should support multibytes characters out of the box.

Comment: Where was the zip file created (Windows, macOS, Linux, etc)? Could you add the output of (1) **echo $LANG** and (2) **echo b*ton_TBF | hexdump -C** (run this command in the same directory where you have extracted `bâton_TBF`) to your answer?

Comment: The zip came from google drive (zip created with this adresse : https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) and I can't not unzip bâtons_TBF/file.zip because it's inside the zip created by google. The output is : **00000000  62 61 25 41 36 25 45 39  74 6f 6e 5f 54 42 46 0a  |ba%A6%E9ton_TBF.|
00000010**

Comment: @MyriamLefebvre Thank you for the information and the link (unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the issue with my data from takeout.google.com). Could you add the part of the ouput of `unzip -l file.zip | hexdump -C` that refers to bâton_TBF (and if possible other file names with accented characters) to your answer (please don't paste the output as a comment, it is difficult to read)? I've encountered similar problems in the past with zipped files from Windows, the underlying problem is that the file names included in the zip archive are encoded in a way that macOS can't properly interpret.